I am learning Linq and getting this error message
This is the error I'm getting:


Title: Trouble with System.Data.Linq Reference in Windows Forms App

Question:
I'm encountering an issue with my Windows Forms application when attempting to use Linq-to-SQL. Here's the sequence of events:

I created a Windows Forms application.
I added a Linq-to-SQL class (LinqToClasses) to the project.
This action automatically generated a .DBML file and associated files like config and designer.cs.
Next, I added a SQL table using the designer in the .DBML file.
However, I noticed that the System.Data.Linq reference was not automatically added to the project.
I then attempted to add the reference manually by including the .dll file.

Despite adding the reference explicitly, I'm encountering an error. The error message is:

Couldnt load file or assembly System.Data.SqlClient

Can someone please advise on how to resolve this issue? Is there a step I'm missing or a specific way to include the System.Data.Linq reference properly in a Windows Forms application using Linq-to-SQL?
Thank you.

Howdid you "include the dll file"? You should "add a reference" to a NuGet package

Linq-to-SQL is quite old technology, why have you decided to use it?

Adding the reference manually could help please try it and checkout the error again.

You really ought to be using Entity Framework rather than LINQ to SQL. You use LINQ to Entities to perform queries in EF, so what you've learned about LINQ will still be applicable. L2S is specific to SQL Server and has not been updated for a long time. EF supports SQL Server and many other data sources too and is constantly being updated with new features. L2S is a dead end.

By the way, LINQ and LINQ to SQL are not the same thing. LINQ is an overarching technology for performing SQL-like queries in .NET code, while LINQ to SQL is a specific LINQ provider for accessing SQL Server databases. There are countless other LINQ providers too, including LINQ to Entities for EF, LINQ to Objects for .NET arrays and collections, LINQ to DataSet for ADO.NET DataTables, etc, etc.

This is because System.Data.Linq.dll is not present in your .Net Framework project. Add it manually, these are the steps -

Right-click on your project in Solution Explorer.
Select "Add" > "Reference...".
In the Reference Manager dialog, go to the "Assemblies" tab.
Scroll down or search for "System.Data.Linq" in the list.
Check the checkbox next to "System.Data.Linq".
Click "OK" to add the reference.

